# Set range for number input in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this type of input in my view:

`Form::number('name', 'value');`

But I would like to set a max and min values to it, I can't seem to find the way using blade.

**In html:**

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
{{Form::number('name', 'value',['min'=>1,'max'=>5])}}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't limited the input :(

Comment: Thanks. Its working for me. `{{Form::number('points', null, ['min'=>0,'max'=>20])}}`